# VS2012 Database Project Does Not Always Open Designer When Double-Clicking on SQL File

Tags: visual-studio-2012, database-project

Perhaps this is just me, but I've noticed that when double-clicking on a .sql file from within a Visual Studio 2012 Database Project, that the designer will not open, and instead focus will go to a previously opened SQL file designer.

This doesn't happen every time (maybe 75% of the time.) Right-clicking and choosing "View Designer" does not work in this situation, either. Though right-clicking and choosing "View Code" does usually work.

Is it just me? If not, what is the problem? What is the solution?

Comment: have you found a solution to this yet?  I'm wondering the same thing.

Comment: Never found a solution. This is just a bug as far as I can tell. I found that if I closed all other open sql files, the one I wanted to open would open.